# Uninstalling Mono in /usr/local/bin

Tags: macos, mono

I had some troubles with my first installation of Mono and reinstalled it building from the source, but I missed the big **bold** letters that said to not install to /usr from source. 
[Compiling Mono on Mac OS X](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/mac/)

Right now I have two mono installations :

- /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.10.0/
- /usr/local/bin

Xamarin Studio is using the first one, and it works. But if I try using the console e.g 
mono "Project.exe"
 An error appears "Missing method .ctor in assembly" 
The /usr/local/bin mono installation is the one that makes the error.
 How do I uninstall mono in /usr/local/bin and fix my mono environment variable to point to the /Library/... mono installation , I want to be able to compile mono from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to still have the directory where you did `make install`.

Then, `cd` into it and do `sudo make uninstall`.

Comment: I tried doing that, but mono -V still shows the mono that I built.

Comment: try to launch a new shell after doing the uninstall